# Why does video load unpredictably?

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I'm having trouble trying to motion track a video, because it loads a frame ahead or behind depending on whether I play or seek through it.

As an example: I load my .blend and then seek to frame 70. Then I open it again, but this time, I play the animation until it reaches frame 70, *then* seek there. All of the trackers are now off.
[image: seeking and playing]

This sort of error isn't good when I'm seeking and playing a lot, as it causes my tracking to look early or late. **Is there a way to fix or work around it?**

Comment: Test with a more [recent build of Blender](https://builder.blender.org/download/), if the problem persists then follow [the bug report procedure](http://archive.blender.org/development/report-a-bug/index.html) , and file a [bug report](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/project/2/) - if it's broken you don't want workarounds, you want it fixed.

Comment: @zeffii No luck... I'll report it.

Comment: More research shows that it's not actually a bug. I won't report it, I guess.

Comment: @MaoHi Nice find! Now that the post is reopened, would you care to put the answer in the answer section down below? The question isn't really the right place to put the answer (but it's understandable given that the question was closed at the time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that this isn't a bug. I found that I have to check "Proxy/timecode" in the movie clip editor and set "Use timecode index" to "Record run." Now it works fine.